# After npm install I received error: Prototype Pollution in set-value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have an app in React Native, and when I run npm install I received this error "found 15 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 10 high) in 1182 scanned packages". After run npm audit the most of error contains this:

> High            Prototype Pollution in set-value
>
> Package         set-value
>
> Patched in      >=4.0.1
>
> Dependency of   react-native
>
> Path            react-native > @react-native-community/cli >
> @react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro > metro-config >
> metro-core > jest-haste-map > sane > anymatch > micromatch >
> braces > snapdragon > base > cache-base > set-value
>
> More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4jqc-8m5r-9rpr

and this:

> Moderate         Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in
> chalk/ansi-regex
>
> Package         ansi-regex
>
> Patched in      >=5.0.1
>
> Dependency of   react-native
>
> Path            react-native > @react-native-community/cli >
> strip-ansi >
> ansi-regex
>
> More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw

Could anyone help me fix these problems?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For `Moderate Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex` see Qix's comment on the following thread: https://github.com/chalk/ansi-regex/commit/8d1d7cdb586269882c4bdc1b7325d0c58c8f76f9

tldr: sanitize user input before it hits an API, if applicable